# Access an element inside an Angular JS directive in Protractor JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

So I have a program that adds a user to a db. When clicking on the add user it calls a custom directive in angular that renders the HTML to the page. In protractor i'm trying to write a test to add a user by finding and filling in the required fields.

So far this works:

```
it('should click the add user button', function(){
    browser.waitForAngular();
    var addUser = element(by.id('addUserDesktop'));
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(addUser), 10000);
    addUser.click().then(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            expect(element(by.id('useradd')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        },2000);
    });
});
```

I've put a setTimeout in it thinking that the element might not be loading fast enough for protractor.

After this passes I have this test:

```
it('should find and enter data into the required fields to add a user', function(){
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys(username);
});
```

But then I'm getting this error:

> ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Anyone got any idea how to get around this have been trying for a little while and it's just got my head wrecked!

Answer (score 0):

In `protractor`, there is a built-in mechanism to wait for specific conditions to be met on the page. In this case [`visibilityOf` Expected Condition](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf) used with [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) should solve the problem:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

addUser.click().then(function() {
    browser.wait(EC.visbilityOf(element(by.id('useradd'))), 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are multiple elements '.username' in the html of this page? Please manually do a find in the html for it on the page as your test would see it, and find out. You can also try something like this:

```
var usernames = $$('.username');
expect(usernames.get(0).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy('First username element not displayed');
```

Just go through each element until you find the one that is actually visible.

Otherwise, I'm thinking a wait may help as @alecxe pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Found out because the directive was loading another html file I had to wait for the Directive to be added. Then target elements inside it. So the "targeting" had to be outer / inner.

```
var directive = element(by.id('useradd'));
    directive.element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys(username);
```

This outer inner targeting ensures that i'm only working on fields inside the directive.